# Why does my tic tac toe minimax algortihm not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I was trying to develop a minimax algorithm for the game tic tac toe. I don't understand why my tic tac toe algorithm doesn't work. The board variable is set up as an array and works like an x and y plane. I would really appreciate it if you could take a look at my code and help me fix any errors I might have. I was looking into getting into AI but I can't really do that if I can't even master this so I'd be really grateful for any time spent on trying to fix my errors.

```py
import copy 

def get_o_win(board):
   if (
          board[0][0] == board[0][1] == board[0][2] == "o"
       or board[1][0] == board[1][1] == board[1][2] == "o"
       or board[2][0] == board[2][1] == board[2][2] == "o"
       or board[0][0] == board[1][0] == board[2][0] == "o"
       or board[0][1] == board[1][1] == board[2][1] == "o"
       or board[0][2] == board[1][2] == board[2][2] == "o"
       or board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] == "o"
       or board[2][0] == board[1][1] == board[0][2] == "o"
       ):
       return True
   else:
       return False

def get_x_win(board):
   if (
          board[0][0] == board[0][1] == board[0][2] == "x"
       or board[1][0] == board[1][1] == board[1][2] == "x"
       or board[2][0] == board[2][1] == board[2][2] == "x"
       or board[0][0] == board[1][0] == board[2][0] == "x"
       or board[0][1] == board[1][1] == board[2][1] == "x"
       or board[0][2] == board[1][2] == board[2][2] == "x"
       or board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] == "x"
       or board[2][0] == board[1][1] == board[0][2] == "x"
       ):
       return True
   else:
       return False

def AI_Turn(board):

   turn = 0

   for _ in board:
       for __ in _:
           if __ != "n":
               turn +=1

   print('turn: '.join(str(turn)))

   o_win = get_o_win(board)
   x_win = get_x_win(board)

   if o_win: # PLAYER WINS
       return (-1, None)

   elif x_win: # AI WINS
       return (1, None)

   elif turn == 9: #TIE
       return (0, None)

   else:
       if turn%2==0: # Player's Turn

           for x in range(3):
               for y in range(3):
                   best = (0, None)
                   board_copy = copy.deepcopy(board)
                   if board_copy[x][y] == "n":
                       board_copy[x][y] = "o"
                       print('User Trying:')
                       print ([''.join(['{:3}'.format(item) for item in row]) for row in board_copy])

                       temporary_score_tuple = AI_Turn(board_copy)
                       best_score = best[0]
                       temporary_score = temporary_score_tuple[0]
                       if temporary_score > best_score:
                           best = (temporary_score,[x,y])

           return best

       else: # AI's Turn

           for x in range(3):
               for y in range(3):
                   best = (0, None)
                   board_copy = copy.deepcopy(board)
                   if board_copy[x][y] == "n":
                       board_copy[x][y] = "x"
                       print('AI Trying:')
                       print ([''.join(['{:3}'.format(item) for item in row]) for row in board_copy])

                       temporary_score_tuple = AI_Turn(board_copy)
                       best_score = best[0]
                       temporary_score = temporary_score_tuple[0] 
                       if temporary_score > best_score:
                           best = (temporary_score,[x,y])

           return best


# n means that there's nothing in that spot
# o means that there is an o in that spot
# x means that there is an x in that spot
# You can alter this board to make it look it look like whatever you need...
board = [['o','x','o'],['x','x','n'],['o','n','n']]

print(AI_Turn(board))
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it but this was written in  python 3

Comment: Hi @Epik_Guy, what does `copy.deepcopy` do? Can you also please include your import statements?

Comment: copy.deepcopy simply makes a copy that also prevents changing the original when changing the copy... And I'm sorry I must've forgotten the first line... It's ```import copy```

Comment: I don't really understand why you're calling the function `AI_Turn` from within the function. That way when you set the `board` variables with all `'n'`s, it runs into an infinite loop

Comment: *"help me fix any errors I might have"* That's not what Stack Overflow is for; if you ask about a specific problem you are having, show the inputs, expected results, and the error message, then it's a good question. Otherwise it is too broad. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: In addition to kaya3's comment: see also https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .